# Create a function that looks at three parameters type

Tags: python

I want to create a function that looks at three parameters and if they are all of the same type to return a boolean True value otherwise false :

This is what I have so far:

```
def whattype(n):
    if type(n) is int:
        print "True"
    elif type(n) != int:
        print "False"
whattype("car")
whattype(1)
whattype(2)
```

Comment: Well for a start your function doesn't have three parameters.

Answer (score 4):

```
def whattype(a, b, c):
    return type(a) == type(b) == type(c)
```

**Explanation**: First of all, your function has to take three arguments (here `a`, `b` and `c`). If you want to return a value, you have to use the `return` statement. Furthermore, it is possible to do multiple comparisons in one line, so you can check the equality of the types in one line and instantly return the result.

You can use the function like this:

```
>>> whattype(1, 2, "car")
False
>>> whattype(1, 2, 3)
True
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure how to write the second line of code you answered here in my previous attempts!